# Catch dropdown selected text inside a repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have dropdownlist inside a repeater and whenever the selected text is changed i have to show it in a textbox how can i do this??

```
 protected void Repeater1_ItemCreated(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("DropDownList6");
    TextBox txt = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("TextBox4");
    txt.Text = ddl.SelectedItem.Text;
}
```

Comment: Your code does not work? what's the problem?

Comment: Are you talking about dynamically on the page, i.e. the moment the user changes the selection of the dropdown... or are you talking about on the post-back of the page?

Comment: After loading the page when the user changes the DDL text it has to be populated in textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't use `ItemCreated` therefore since it triggered too early in the life-cycle(for the ViewState). You would also have to check for the `ItemType` first.

Instead use the `DropDownLists` `SelectedIndexChanged` event directly:

```
protected void Ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl   = (DropDownList)  sender;
    RepeaterItem item  = (RepeaterItem)  ddl .NamingContainer;
    TextBox txt        = (TextBox) item.FindControl("TextBox4");
    txt.Text           = ddl.SelectedItem.Text;
}
```

Comment: How can i get this in the code behind as i have the control in a repeater?

Comment: How can i call this event? Ddl_SelectedIndexChanged?

Comment: You just have to register this event handler, for example on aspx: `<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList6" runat="server" 
        onselectedindexchanged="Ddl_SelectedIndexChanged">
    </asp:DropDownList>`

Comment: I have done that but when i change the text nothing is happening.

Comment: @Newbie: You cannot change the text of a `DropDownList`, it is not a winforms ComboBox. However, you can change the selected index, then this event is triggered normally. A possible reason when it's not triggered could be that you're always binding the repeater to it's datasource on postbacks. You should check for `if(!IsPostBack)BindMyRepeater();` in Page_Load.

Comment: Do you have `AutoPostBack="True"` on the DDL?

Comment: I am getting Object reference not set to an instance of an object at here txt.Text= ddl.SelectedItem.Text;

Comment: Then either your TextBox' ID is not "TextBox4" or the DropDown SelectedItem is null(impossible since we are in SelectedIndexChanged). Maybe you want to edit your question and add the repeater aspx.

Answer (score 0):

you could add appropriate OnSelectedChange (somwthing) event handler to the DropDownList and then when event fired you catch it and do whatever you want , you can do it in both client side or server side .

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the add a handler to associate each dropdown control with the appropriate event handler.  I don't have VS in front of me but it should be something like:

txt.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(YourMethodName)